# Android Push Notifications not receiving when app is terminated (task manager swipe)

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can not receive push notification when application is terminated (swipe in task manager). Problem is only on android. When app is in the background or foreground everything works fine. When it is terminated - no push notification. On iOS it works fine when app is in foreground, background or terminated. Backend send notification with data & notification payload.

packages:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.11.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.5.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.2.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
```

main.dart

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<dynamic> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    RemoteMessage message) async {
  await FCMService.instance.setupBasics(); // contains 'Firebase.initializeApp()', executes only once
  await FCMService.instance.showFlutterNotification(message);
}

Future<void> main() async {

  try {

    WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    await FCMService.instance.setupBasics(); // contains 'Firebase.initializeApp()', executes only once

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
}
```

Testing in debug mode. Strange thing is this: when swiped in task manager, the app is totally terminated with all services. App cant be terminated in System application info: 'Force close' button is greyed out.
Other apps do not have this issue when swiped in task manager: 'Force close' button is not greyed out.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that android studio debugger is the problem. When my app is running and debugger is attached via usb cable or WIFI - no push notification is received when app is terminated. Without cable / WIFI debugger attached - everything works fine.

Comment: same with vs code. push notification not received on android after app terminated when running from vs code, but if disconnect cable like you suggested, push notification works as expected. thank you @jason